# npm is properly installed but node version is not coming up on widows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

**when i checked for node version, i got the response bellow**

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> node -v

Node Commands

Syntax:

```
node {operator} [options] [arguments]
```

Parameters:

```
    /? or /help   - Display this help message.


    list          - List nodes or node history or the cluster

    listcores     - List cores on the cluster

    view          - View properties of a node

    online        - Set nodes or node to online state

    offline       - Set one or more nodes to the offline state
```

For more information about HPC command-line tools,
see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=120724.

**but checking for npm version, it comes up well.**

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm -v
8.5.0
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>

**npm -v gives 8.5.0**

**But node -v give syntax results as shown above**

**is the node properly installed??**

**how do I show the node version on the code??**

I have tried to use the node -v

I have also tried to correct the PATH in environment variables,

I have used node repair, I have uninstall and reinstall but yet I still can't see the node version, but the npm version is coming up.

**how can the npm version show up but the node version doesn't show?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the system32 folder and running as an admin user, and `node` is a Windows executable. You probably want to be running the 'nodejs command prompt' instead of cmd.exe.

Comment: Thanks, on the node command prompt, it shows the node version, but now I can't install react, it will bring up the same issue result when I try to use npx on my vscode terminal ...

Comment: @Renner'sClouds Don't use the vscode terminal, use the node prompt? That's all I have to say. If this solved your question, please press the big check to accept it as the answer.